# Issues trying to construct `std::vector` with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initializer-list

Consider the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
  explicit A(std::vector<int> &&v) : v_(std::move(v)) {}

private:
  std::vector<int> v_;
};

int main() {
  // compilation error (no matching call to std::make_unique)
  // compiler output: https://ideone.com/4oKjCS
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> as1 = {std::make_unique<A>({1}),
                                         std::make_unique<A>({2})};

  // compilation error (requested copy of std::unique_ptr)
  // compiler output: https://ideone.com/5LGPoa
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> as2 = {
      std::make_unique<A>(std::vector<int>({1})),
      std::make_unique<A>(std::vector<int>({2}))};

  // succeeds
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> as3;
  as3.push_back(std::make_unique<A>(std::vector<int>({1})));
  as3.push_back(std::make_unique<A>(std::vector<int>({2})));
}
```

- For `as1`: I would expect `std::make_unique<A>({1})` to call the implicit initializer list constructor of `std::vector`, then pass the vector to `std::make_unique`. Why doesn't this compile?
- For `as2`: The result of `std::make_unique` is an rvalue. Why is a copy requested anywhere?
- Is there a more idiomatic or shorter way to accomplish this than my `as3`?

Edit: I am now remembering the reason for the error in `as1`. Meyers' *Effective Modern C++* mentions initializer lists in Item 30 as one of the failure cases of perfect forwarding: "passing a braced initializer to a function template parameter that’s not declared to be a `std::initializer_list` is decreed to be, as the Standard puts it, a 'non-deduced context.'"

Answer (score 3):

## as1

Make unique uses "perfect forwarding".  Perfect forwarding is imperfect, and does not support initializer lists very well.

## as2

initializer lists are (pairs of) pointers to an automatic storage duration `const` array.  `const` objects cannot be moved from, and instead are copied from.  You cannot copy unique ptrs.

## as3

```
template<class T, class...Ts>
std::vector<T> make_vector(Ts&&...ts){
  std::array<T,sizeof...(ts)> tmp={{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}};
  std::vsctor<T> r{
    std::make_move_iterator(begin(tmp)),
    std::make_move_iterator(end(tmp))
  };
}
```

Giving us:

```
auto as4=make_vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>(
  std::make_unique<A>(make_vector<int>(1)),
  std::make_unique<A>(make_vector<int>(2))
);
```

This may not be ideal, but a unique ptr of objects that are thin wrappers around vectors is a bad idea.

In a more complex case, a helper function that makes a unique A directly would cut down boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the `std::unique_ptr`, not the `std::initializer_list`. Values from `std::initializer_list` are copied via  temporary buffer to the destination object. `unique_ptr` is not copyable. You need to initialize it another way, maybe via `reserve()/emplace_back()`.

I'm sorry, I know this sounds infuriating, but there really is **no** good way to use an initializer list for this purpose.

The following example shows how you could use a temporary vector of raw pointers, with an initializer list. The example isn't pretty, and I wouldn't recommend it for any real code, but if you are set on an initializer list, it will work with `std::unique_ptr`, and introduce no memory leaks as long as the constructor does not throw.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


int main(void)
{
    std::vector<int*> v = {
        new int(1),
        new int(2),
        new int(3),
        new int(4),
    };

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v1(v.begin(), v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Instead, I would recommend something much more akin to your original example: using `reserve`/`emplace_back()`. Maybe a little more verbose, but the intention is clear, and the syntax is much more idiomatic.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
v.reserve(50);
for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(i));
}
```

The latter is the only memory-safe solution with constructors that may throw, as Henri points out in the comments. You should use the latter example in all real code.

Comment: The example with `int` will work fine in any case because `new int` can only throw `bad_alloc` from which you cannot recover anyway.  It is much more problematic with custom datatypes whose constructors might throw, because then you would leak memory from the partially initialized vector of raw pointers.  The `emplace_back` solution is the only fail-safe one. (+1)